# PhpStorm + Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, phpstorm

How can I set tab in *.vue files as 4 spaces for template and style blocks, but as 2 spaces for script block? I have 4 spaces in *.vue files now for all blocks

I have installed Vue.js plugin; *.vue files have type "Vue.js Template".

There are 2 spaces in the Code Style settings for JavaScript (**Settings | Editor | Code Style | JavaScript | Tabs and Indents**)

and 4 spaces in **Settings | Editor | Code Style | HTML | Tabs and Indents** and **Settings | Editor | Code Style | CSS | Tabs and Indents**

I have no .editorconfig file https://ibb.co/k1ubJe and even a settings for .editorconfig (**Settings | Editor | Code Style, Enable Editorconfig support**) https://ibb.co/e4zkde

Comment: Settings mentioned by you should work; the only issue is that the code in `<script>` block is shifted to the right instead of being aligned with tags. This is a known problem, caused by the lack of dedicated code style settings for .vue files; it's tracked as https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-30382. As a workaround, try adding `script` and `style` entries into *Settings | Editor | Code Style | HTML | Other, Do not indent children of* list.

Comment: if it doesn't help, please create a support ticket, providing a sample project plus your code style settings